# How to us a Subquery to Update Multiple Column Values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

My ultimate goal is to be able to update multiple column values from one table to another without having to write each one out.

I found the following on IBM's site the indicated how to do it ([Link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1265.htm))

```
UPDATE items
   SET (stock_num, manu_code, quantity) = 
      ( (SELECT stock_num, manu_code FROM stock 
         WHERE description = 'baseball'), 2)
   WHERE item_num = 1 AND order_num = 1001;

UPDATE table1
   SET (col1, col2, col3) =
      ((SELECT MIN (ship_charge), MAX (ship_charge) FROM orders), '07/01/2007')
   WHERE col4 = 1001;
```

I took this and attempted to create it on my end, but I keep getting an "Incorrect syntax near '('" error.

```
UPDATE XX__JeremyTempTable2
    SET (OP__DOCID, SexualPrefCode) =
        (SELECT OP__DOCID, SexualPrefCode FROM FD__CLIENTS 
         WHERE CLIENTKEY = 726148)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Off the top of my head, IBM has Netezza, Informix, DB2/UDB . . . and probably others.

Comment: We are using a SQL-Server. 

I am still pretty "new" at coding, could this be the reason why the multiple column update isn't working? It only works on the informix servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MS Sql server your query will be

```
UPDATE XX__JeremyTempTable2
    SET OP__DOCID = FD__CLIENTS.OP__DOCID,
        SexualPrefCode = FD__CLIENTS.SexualPrefCode
    FROM FD__CLIENTS 
    WHERE FD__CLIENTS.CLIENTKEY = 726148
```

With such errors you need check [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql)

**Edit** Changed to your target query.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the Link I found on IBM's site is for a different server than I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set each variable separately:

```
UPDATE XX__JeremyTempTable2
    SET OP__DOCID = (SELECT OP__DOCID FROM FD__CLIENTS WHERE CLIENTKEY = 726148) ,
    SexualPrefCode = (SELECT SexualPrefCode FROM FD__CLIENTS WHERE CLIENTKEY = 726148)
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well, however, that link I provided indicated that it is possible, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I don't feel like it has a great answer so I'm adding one.

To use a subselect in an update statement in MS sql server, you have to do a subselect per column as noted by Rominus, which is not terribly satisfying -  especially if the subselect is complicated and could easily produce all of the values needing updated.

You cannot mangle Vitaliy Smolyakov's answer in any way that would produce this result; replacing `FROM FD__CLIENTS` with `(select this, that from thing) as FD__CLIENTS` does not work, and I tried this a frustrating number of times using his answer.

What you can do instead, is use a Merge statement to update the table.

Before:

```
    UPDATE items
       SET (stock_num, manu_code, quantity) = 
          ( (SELECT stock_num, manu_code FROM stock 
             WHERE description = 'baseball'), 2)
       WHERE item_num = 1 AND order_num = 1001;
```

After:

```
    MERGE items
    USING(SELECT item_num, stock_num, manu_code FROM stock 
         WHERE description = 'baseball') AS BB
    ON items.item_num=BB.item_num
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
    items.stock_num=BB.stock_num,
    items.manu_code=BB.manu_code,
    items.quantity=2
    WHERE item_num = 1 AND order_num = 1001;
```